# Create script protocol buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

[image]
Using the image as reference where would the .proto be used?

**old**

> > .
>
> I need to create a script in protocol buffers.

What I want is to create a delay of 20 minutes (1200 seconds), for every bus, of the specific route, and during a specific time, from 08:30:00 until 09:30:00 (am time).
The bus route is identified as 9403 (from x to y), and 9404 (from y to x).
Is this correct?

```
syntax = "proto3";

package teste1;


message TripUpdate {
    string agency_id = 1;
    string route_id = 9403, 9404;
        
    message DelayConstruction{
        uint64 start 08:30:00;
        uint64 end 09:30:00;
        int32 delay 1200; //20min
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.proto is not a scripting language - it is a schema DSL: it *just* describes the metadata of a potential future payload; it is the equivalent of XSD in terms of XML, for example.

Each field has *only* one field number, as indicated by `= {the number}` , so `string route_id = 9403, 9404;` doesn't make sense. Likewise, the `start`, `end` and `delay` fields are *field definitions* here - they just have field numbers, not values like `08:30:00`. Serialized *data* may have values, but that is not encoded in .proto - it is going to be either the binary protobuf format, or (sometimes, rarely) the JSON variant of protobuf.

It is very hard to understand what you are trying to do, but no: this isn't how you do it, regardless of what "it" is.

It may be worth trying to explain *what you're trying to do*, so we can offer guidance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/guides/trip-updates
what I want is to create a delay on a specific bus route, but instead of being for stop x is supose to be for a time lenght.

Comment: @RuiM20 right; so what you're trying to do is create a *payload* that is an *instance* of the required message type, with values corresponding to your update? That isn't something you do in .proto itself; you do that in whatever language you're using, after having run the .proto schema through "protoc" (or similar tooling) for your required platform / language

Comment: thank you.
Was having some dificulty with the google guide

Comment: Can you tell me where on the image I would I use the .proto file?

Comment: @RuiM20 to generate the message types in code suitable for whatever your target platform is; so if you're using Java, for example, the .proto is used to create a bunch of Java classes that represent the object model used in that API, along with the code to serialize/deserialize them